# Как затестировать дату с помощью моков

Tags: java

Пишу код для тестирования метода, он принимает параметры: Long, LocalDate, LocalDate. Как мне на даты проверить? Хочу принимать любую дату.

```
Mockito.verify(contractService, Mockito.times(1))
     .findAllByDate(
   ArgumentMatchers.anyLong(),
   ArgumentMatchers.anyLocalDate(),
   ArgumentMatchers.anyLocalDate()
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any(LocalDate.class) - если не null, org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any() - если и null тоже